# RESTful API - Can't decide which route form to use

Tags: rest

I have dilemma about choosing the right route for my problem.
I have food entries in my database and also the photos of this food. So when I want to list all photos of some food I would use this route:

```
GET /food/{id}/photos
```

When I want to add some photo to some food I use this:

```
POST /food/{id}/photos
```

Now problem is deleting the photo of the food. Because every user can post more photos of the same food, I cannot simply use this one:

```
DELETE /food/{id}/photos
```

I see two possible ways to solve this problem:

```
DELETE /food/{food_id}/photos/{photo_id}
DELETE /photos/{id}
```

About the first one i like consistency with other photo routes. But i don't like redundancy in form of food id, because every photo has unique id, so food id is irrelevant in this case.

The second solution is more clean, but there is no consistency with other routes. I mean creating photo is via /food/ prefix and deleting is without this prefix.

Which route do you suggest to use?

Comment: If there is ever a chance you wanted to delete all photos for a given food item then the first one will give you that flexibility

Comment: As the design of your URI is not of relevance to any client adhering to the RESTful architecture any answers you will get are primarily opinion-based, hence I voted for an according close reason as there are also plenty of similar questions available here at SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Rest URL ***DELETE /food/{food_id}/photos/{photo_id}*** suits as better solution compared to ***DELETE /photos/{id}***.

Since i as read URL ***/food/{food_id}/photos/{photo_id}***,i read it like 'Delete photo for a particular food' which is your requirement, where as if you try to read ***DELETE /photos/{id}***, delete photo with photo id, but it does not tell you for which food you are deleting photo.

**For further reading:**

1. https://hackernoon.com/restful-api-designing-guidelines-the-best-practices-60e1d954e7c9
2. http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

**Note:** See the examples for DELETE resources.

Comment: This is well explained. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `'/food/{food_id}/photos/{photo_id}'`, photo_id doesn't have to be globally unique. It's enough if it's unique in the context of `'/food/{food_id}'`. It means you don't have to use UUID or such large structures with low probability of collision. It can be a simple increasing number or even a short readable text.

Using `/food/{food_id}/photos/{photo_id}` also scales better because you have the opportunity to handle resources on different servers and the hierarchical URI gives some chance to implement a routing.

If you use `/photos/{id}`, all photos should be kept in some kind of global store (unless id have some internal structure).

Comment: I have some issues with the second paragraph. Scaling is usually achived by having multiple servers providing the same data not by spliting the data among many servers as if one server dies certain requests will not be processable and hence decrease the scalability. If photos have unique IDs there is actually no big difference between `/photos/{id}` or `/food/{food_id}/photos/{photos_id}`. A true RESTful client doesn't even care how the URI is set up in first place!

Comment: For a true RESTful client indeed doesn't care about the URL. Well my scaling example maybe wasn't the best, though it's possible to have storing data redundantly AND partitioning the data at the same time. I thought about scaling as generally managing larger amounts of data. For example analyzing request logs or creating metrics is simpler with an URI structure which represents the underlying model. (This time, that photos belong to food.)